# What is local.blackjack from Netstat?

Tags: network, security, malware, macos, daemons

When running `netstat` I noticed the suspicious name `blackjack`. I wonder if it's malware.

```
PROMPT> netstat -v
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)     rhiwat shiwat    pid   epid  state    options
tcp6       0      0  nameofmachine.local.blackjack fe80::c55b:ddf6:.13569 ESTABLISHED 131072 131072    476      0 0x0102 0x00000204
tcp6       0      0  nameofmachine.local.1024      fe80::c55b:ddf6:.1024  ESTABLISHED 131072 131072    476      0 0x0102 0x00000204
```

Looking up the pid `476`

```
PROMPT> ps ax | grep 476
476   ??  S      0:19.94 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/MacOS/identityservicesd
```

So the process that owns the address seems to be `identityservicesd.app`, which is an Apple process. This is where my trail ends.

There are other mentions of `.blackjack` occurring on macOS, see [this unanswered Reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeNetworking/comments/cmj92b/blackjack_when_running_netstat/).

#### Question: What is it? Malware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By giving an extra `-n` parameter to the `netstat` command, reveals the port number.

This reveals that `blackjack` correspond to the port `1025`.

```
PROMPT> netstat -anv
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)     rhiwat shiwat    pid   epid  state    options
tcp6       0      0  fe80::c999:dc6f:.1025  fe80::c55b:ddf6:.13569 ESTABLISHED 131072 131072    476      0 0x0102 0x00000204
tcp6       0      0  fe80::c999:dc6f:.1024  fe80::c55b:ddf6:.1024  ESTABLISHED 131072 131072    476      0 0x0102 0x00000204
```

In the past, port 1025 seems to have been used for something named [network blackjack](https://www.grc.com/port_1025.htm). Nowadays I doubt that it's still being used for this purpose.

My conclusion is that `identityservicesd` running on port 1024+1025 is harmless.

Comment: Are those port-to-service mappings even still maintained?

Comment: The port mappings seems outdated. I'm on the newest macOS version, and see blackjack both in `netstat` and `lsof`.

Comment: I have submitted this issue to Apple using the Feedback Assistant.

Answer (score -1):

Run the command below to get the pid of the process.  I can't get the pid because I just killed the process and it is not coming back.

```
sh-3.2# lsof -i | grep ESTABLISHED
```

Once you have the PID run this:

```
sh-3.2# lsof -p 1049 | grep txt
```

replace the number after the `-p` with the real PID of the process.  I will report back if I see this process pops up again.

Comment: PID is never consistent across machines and vary over time (apart from the first launched process). So there is no point in determining the PID of the process on your machine as it will not help the OP.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The second command in my list will show the binary that makes the process.  It is the Mac equivalent to checking the proc filesystem in Linux for the executable.

Comment: Yes, I know what it does. But in your answer you state that you will try to find the PID of the process on your machine. But knowing that PID on *your machine* will not help the OP. It might be better to change the second command line to `sh-3.2# lsof -p <PID> | grep txt`, or something (more generic) like that. Unless, you are just trying to provide an example of its use on your machine, which could also work

Comment: I saw the same process on my machine and I killed it before running the second command.  If the process shows up again I will look and find the binary instead of killing it.  I will post the binary here if it shows up again.